# Keep the event, but avoid on links(or inner content)

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is probably asked a thousand of times, but I can't find an answer...

Here is an example:

```js
var div = $('.div');
div.on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  div.toggleClass('red');
});
```

```css
.div {
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  background: #eee;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  <a href="#">link</a>
</div>
```

The problem: event triggered when link(any content) is clicked.

I want remain the event, but avoid when content is clicked/selected/whatever. What are my options here?

Thanks

Comment: So, you want the `div` to be clickable, but not the `a`? It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I want to keep the event on div, but keep the link clickable. If the link has `href="google.com"` I want to be able click it and go to google.com :) But it's not about specific link, but content in general inside of a div like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set up a "click" event handler for any child element of the `div.div` that prevents that event from bubbling up to any ancestor elements. This can be done with the **[`*` (universal) CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors)**.

Unless, you have reason to that you haven't described here, you don't need:

```
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
```

in the `div` event handler.

```js
var div = $('.div');
div.on('click', function(e) {
  div.toggleClass('red');
});

// When any child element of the div with class .div is clicked...
$("div.div > *").on("click", function(evt){
  // Don't allow the event to bubble up to the ancestor elements
  evt.stopPropagation();
  console.log("You clicked some child element of the div, but the event won't bubble up to it.");
});
```

```css
.div {
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  background: #eee;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  <a href="http://google.com">link</a>
  <span>Clicking me will do nothing</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, I guess so... I will be able to use the link as intended, right? (`href="yahoo.com"`) will go to yahoo.com? If yes, is there any elegant(and more efficient) way to handle this kind of things? For example, if I will have a content inside a div, say `<span>Lorem...</span><p>Impsum...</p>` etc. It will be ugly to put the `stopPropagation` in each

Comment: That's correct and my last update to my answer addresses this for any kind of child content by using the `*` (universal) selector.

Comment: @wezod You're welcome. Don't forget to mark as "the" answer.